# get error code of #10415 in paypal in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

got following error massage in paypal of magento.

"PayPal gateway has rejected request.A successful transaction has already been completed for this token (#10415: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)."

can anyone help me to solution about it.

I checked paypal details its perfect.

Comment: Can you send the error log with full detail

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to create an order, using PayPal, with ID that you already have in your PayPal account. Check your transaction data in the PayPal account.