# Security Patch SUPEE-10415 - Possible Issues?

Tags: magento-1, patches, security, supee-10415

New Magento 1 patch has been released, **SUPEE-10415**.

> This patch provides protection against several types of security-related issues

Info page: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10415
Download page: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

What are the possible issues to watch out?

Also, please share all the bugs and problems that you have found after patch install.

---

- Issue with applying SUPEE-10415 on vanilla **1.9.1.1**, shows cannot be applied due to hunk error message at **Image.php**.
  **EDIT: As of Dec 7, 2017 fix is provided in SUPEE-10497**
- Must have **8788 Versions 2** installed, otherwise will see "Unsupported data type" errors. [More info.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203795/35443)
- **"404: Page Not Found"** error from the errors/ directory after upgrading to SUPEE-10415. This issue occurs only in Magento installations that run certain third-party extensions.
  ***Workaround:*** Confirm that there are no PHP warnings generated by any of the extensions or customizations.

Comment: Deployed with no issues on Magento 1.9.2.4CE here - most of the changes seem to be sanitation of variables in admin, specifically log file saving. There appears to be a few changes to the soap api also in terms of sanitizing. Reviews are also sanitized in the admin area, so there may be a possible exploit where malicious code can be posted into a review at the mo (speculative)

Comment: Deployed to Magento 1.9.3.0 CE no issues here.
The patch before it 10266 is required if you have not already applied that patch.

Comment: On 1.9.1.0 - in the "Shopping Cart Price Rules" the patch causes a failure - hard error on view rule - log entry -a:5:{i:0;s:23:"Unsupported data type N";i:1;s:1464:"#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php(102): Unserialize_Reader_ArrValue->read('N', ';') ---- patch reversion fixed so it is something in SUPEE-10415

Comment: I don't have the reputation to post an answer, but you cannot upgrade to Magento 1.9.3.7 and then use Git to merge with this patch: the MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH constant gets added twice if you use the default Git behavior (no idea if there are settings that are workarounds for this).

Comment: For 1.9.1.1 issues: Please use SUPEE-10497 instead, it was just recently released to address this problem on 1.9.1.1. Please read the release notes as this patch requires removing SUPEE-10266 prior to installation.

Comment: anybody get reports from Magento Security scan that this patch not detected? I tested if I applied this patch before, and I did. But the security report comes back as not secure. I also ran MageReport and that one passes. So not sure if it's glitchy report from Magento or MageReport. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26):

The below files are updated/added after applied patch **SUPEE - 10415.**

```
app/Mage.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Review/Detail.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Tag/Product/Detail.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Add.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Filename.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Serialized.php
app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php
app/code/core/Zend/Form/Decorator/Form.php
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/billing/agreement/view/tab/info.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/content.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/image_edit.phtml
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
js/mage/adminhtml/backup.js
lib/Varien/Filter/FormElementName.php
```

---

**Some Important points :**

1) Allowed file extensions: log, txt, html, csv.  check in below files

```
app/Mage.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Filename.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php
```

2) Maximum password length set is 256 character and validation check in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` file

```
@@ -74,6 +74,11 @@ class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
     const MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;

     /**
+     * Maximum Password Length
+     */
+    const MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 256;
+
+    /**
      * Model event prefix
      *
      * @var string
@@ -876,6 +881,10 @@ class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
             $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
                 ->__('The minimum password length is %s', self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
         }
+        if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array('max' => self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
+            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
+                ->__('Please enter a password with at most %s characters.', self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
+        }
         $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
         if ($password != $confirmation) {
             $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
@@ -902,7 +911,7 @@ class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
     }

     /**
-     * Validate customer attribute values on password reset
+     * Validate customer password on reset
      * @return bool
      */
     public function validateResetPassword()
@@ -916,6 +925,10 @@ class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
             $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
                 ->__('The minimum password length is %s', self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
         }
+        if (!Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array('max' => self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
+            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
+                ->__('Please enter a password with at most %s characters.', self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
+        }
         $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
         if ($password != $confirmation) {
             $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
```

---

**For EE Edition Added additional four files**

```
app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/List.php
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/smartmerch/tab.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
```

**Some improtant points in EE**

**Added a condition in the below files**

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml 
  app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
```

**Please update the below condition in your Theme files.**

```
if (elements[i].name == 'form_key') 
{
                continue;
 }
```

---

**For more information:**

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10415
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ee1.14_release-notes.html#ee114-11436
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1936

Comment: After apply SUPEE-10415, both front-end and back-end getting 404 error, how can i solve this issue?  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215620/57334

Comment: Can you create a separate ticket and explain with error log and Add a comment  I will help you.  this problem because of .htaccess or override the module in local.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215620/57334

Answer (score 20):

SUPEE-10415...

1. Resolves some admin panel XSS issues in the following areas:

   - Product reviews report
   - Product tags report
   - Product reviews add/edit interface
   - Billing agreements
   - xmlconnect content editor tab
   - Serialized rules
2. Restricts file extensions that can be used for the system and exception log files. Allowed file extensions: `.log`, `.txt`, `.html`, `.csv`
3. Places a 256-character upper limit on customer account passwords. This particular change is ridiculous; not sure where they got this bright idea from.

None of these changes appear to be massively breaking or backward-incompatible changes, except perhaps for the customer password length restriction.

Comment: The 256 password length is actually a bug in unpatched Magento, because the database password field is in customer_entity_varchar.value which is maxlength = 255. Unsure what happens without patch if you try to set longer than 255, probably causes an issue though.

Comment: You're correct; customer_entity_varchar.value does have a limited column size. However, it is not a bug because the password is not stored in that column. The _salted and hashed_ password is stored there. This value will always have a fixed length, regardless of the size of the original password. Prior to this patch, there would have been absolutely no problem entering a password longer than 255 characters.

Comment: I'm assuming the password length change has something to do with APPSEC-1330. https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10415

Comment: The password length does not effect the admin side for setting customer's passwords

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce the DoS in 1.9.3.6 to better understand the potential impact and manual fix and a password longer than 256 characters isn't causing an issue.

Comment: Perhaps this is their thinking, Rob: https://stackoverflow.com/a/98857/8199523

Comment: @t-richards great point, you're right there. Why'd you think they'd do it, I'm thinking maybe to hash a long password could cause a DoS issue in terms of CPU usage, surely a longer password takes more CPU / Memory in PHP to hash?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the password maximum is because hashing a 100 digit password can cause serious DOS.

Comment: Magento 1's default hashing algorithms are MD5 for CE, and SHA256 for EE. Measured on my local workstation, hashing a 1000 character password using either of these methods takes less tham 5ms. Unless you're allowing site users to POST hundreds of MB of data into the password field, these hashing algorithms are far too fast to be a DoS risk.

`$ time head -c 1000 /dev/urandom | md5sum`

Answer (score 12):

### SUPEE 10415 Requires 8788 v2 patch

I encountered the same error as a previous post but it seems to have been removed.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:23:"Unsupported data type N";i:1;s:2942:"#0 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php(102): Unserialize_Reader_ArrValue->  read('N', ';')
#1 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/lib/Unserialize/Parser.php(53): Unserialize_Reader_Arr->read('N', ';')
#2 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php(44): Unserialize_Parser->unserialize('a:6:{s:4:"type"...')
#3 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php(179): Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray->unserialize('a:6:{s:4:"type"...')
#4 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php(353): Mage_Rule_Model_Abstract->getConditions()
#5 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php(216): Mage_Rule_Model_Abstract->validate(Object(   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#6 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php(242): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator->_canProcessRule(Object(  Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule), Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#7 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Quote/Freeshipping.php(74): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator->processFreeShipping(Object(  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#8 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(1013): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping->collect(Object(    Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#9 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1331): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectTotals()
#10 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(458): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()
#11 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(127): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
#12 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
#13 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#14 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(   Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /chroot/home/mywebroot/html/index.php(96): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}";s:3:"url";s:15:"/checkout/cart/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I Encountered the above error when I installed the new patch on M 1.8.00 CE 
The specific cause seems to be due to having the v2 patch of 8788 we made manual fixes for the majority of issues from that patch but we missed the unserialize portions.

Instead of reverting the patch I manually made the modifications and now the site is working properly.

Below you will find the code for the 8788 patch

```
diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
index 423902a..2c01684 100644
--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
@@ -34,6 +34,7 @@ class Unserialize_Parser
     const TYPE_DOUBLE = 'd';
     const TYPE_ARRAY = 'a';
     const TYPE_BOOL = 'b';
+    const TYPE_NULL = 'N';

     const SYMBOL_QUOTE = '"';
     const SYMBOL_SEMICOLON = ';';
```

---

```
diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
index caa979e..cd37804 100644
--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
@@ -101,7 +101,10 @@ class Unserialize_Reader_Arr
         if ($this->_status == self::READING_VALUE) {
             $value = $this->_reader->read($char, $prevChar);
             if (!is_null($value)) {
-                $this->_result[$this->_reader->key] = $value;
+                $this->_result[$this->_reader->key] =
+                    ($value == Unserialize_Reader_Null::NULL_VALUE && $prevChar == Unserialize_Parser::TYPE_NULL)
+                        ? null
+                        : $value;
                 if (count($this->_result) < $this->_length) {
                     $this->_reader = new Unserialize_Reader_ArrKey();
                     $this->_status = self::READING_KEY;
```

---

```
diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
index d2a4937..c6c0221 100644
--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
@@ -84,6 +84,10 @@ class Unserialize_Reader_ArrValue
                     $this->_reader = new Unserialize_Reader_Dbl();
                     $this->_status = self::READING_VALUE;
                     break;
+                case Unserialize_Parser::TYPE_NULL:
+                    $this->_reader = new Unserialize_Reader_Null();
+                    $this->_status = self::READING_VALUE;
+                    break;
                 default:
                     throw new Exception('Unsupported data type ' . $char);
             }
```

---

```
diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..93c7e0b
--- /dev/null
+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
@@ -0,0 +1,64 @@
+<?php
+/**
+ * Magento
+ *
+ * NOTICE OF LICENSE
+ *
+ * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
+ * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
+ * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
+ * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
+ * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
+ * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
+ * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
+ *
+ * DISCLAIMER
+ *
+ * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
+ * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
+ * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
+ *
+ * @category    Unserialize
+ * @package     Unserialize_Reader_Null
+ * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
+ * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
+ */
+
+/**
+ * Class Unserialize_Reader_Null
+ */
+class Unserialize_Reader_Null
+{
+    /**
+     * @var int
+     */
+    protected $_status;
+
+    /**
+     * @var string
+     */
+    protected $_value;
+
+    const NULL_VALUE = 'null';
+
+    const READING_VALUE = 1;
+
+    /**
+     * @param string $char
+     * @param string $prevChar
+     * @return string|null
+     */
+    public function read($char, $prevChar)
+    {
+        if ($prevChar == Unserialize_Parser::SYMBOL_SEMICOLON) {
+            $this->_value = self::NULL_VALUE;
+            $this->_status = self::READING_VALUE;
+            return null;
+        }
+
+        if ($this->_status == self::READING_VALUE && $char == Unserialize_Parser::SYMBOL_SEMICOLON) {
+            return $this->_value;
+        }
+        return null;
+    }
+}
```

You can also read more about the error from this post [SOLVED: new Unserialize_Parser class throws exceptions on NULL values](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140791/solved-new-unserialize-parser-class-throws-exceptions-on-null-values)

Comment: aha! good point, 8788 V2 is required to prevent the issue!

Comment: Can you please tell, on what pages of your website did you see "Unsupported data type " errors? Trying to replicate.

Comment: I was able to trigger it on the category page and product page and cart while a product was in the cart.

Comment: @danmentzer how can i solve the error, revert patch 9767 v1 :: error : https://justpaste.it/1e9pn

Comment: @zus I just saw your post did you get this figured out from the looks of your paste I would venture a guess of three different possible reasons for your error.
1. You have  the wrong patch version (This is the least most likely)
2. Your patch is already unapplied.
3. Maybe you manually fixed some of those and the patch doesn't like how you did it.
Sorry if this isn't helpful

Comment: @danmentzer Glad to receive message from you after long time. Actually the error solved, i just forward to testing and solved the issue.

Comment: @zus glad you got it taken care of cheers!

Answer (score 11):

We've had an issue with this patch where the every page on the site started showing "404: Page Not Found" error from the `errors/` directory. After a little digging it turns out it was caused by a PHP Warning issued in `Mage_Core_Model_App::init`, which then causes a `Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception` in the following lines from the patch:

```
diff --git app/Mage.php app/Mage.php
index 566027d..165928d 100644
--- app/Mage.php
+++ app/Mage.php
@@ -805,7 +805,12 @@ final class Mage
         static $loggers = array();

         $level  = is_null($level) ? Zend_Log::DEBUG : $level;
-        $file = empty($file) ? 'system.log' : $file;
+        $file = empty($file) ? 'system.log' : basename($file);
+
+        // Validate file extension before save. Allowed file extensions: log, txt, html, csv
+        if (!self::helper('log')->isLogFileExtensionValid($file)) {
+            return;
+        }

         try {
             if (!isset($loggers[$file])) {
```

1. A PHP Warning happens before stores have been initialized
2. The warning gets picked up by `mageCoreErrorHandler()`, which calls `Mage::log()` to log the message into the log file.
3. `Mage::log()` calls `Mage::helper('log')`
4. `Mage_Log_Helper_Data::__construct` calls `Mage::getStoreConfig()`, which calls `Mage::app()->getStore()`, but the stores haven't been initialized yet and a `Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception` is thrown
5. `app/Mage.php:647` catches the exception and returns a 404 page

Not really sure what the solution is as of yet, other than fixing the warning and/or catching the exception when checking the log file extension. Going to report this to Magento to see what they think.

Comment: what version you using?

Comment: @Icon 1.9.3.6. I did notice that some of our less-up-to-date projects didn't have the `__construct()` method in `Mage_Log_Helper_Data`, so wouldn't be affected by this, but both the latest community and enterprise editions do.

Comment: Looks like magento addressed this question http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html

Comment: Did magento mention whether they plan on fixing this issue with next patch?

Comment: @Icon Nah, they said they'd document it, but it doesn't warrant a v2 patch. On our end we just ended up fixing the code that's producting the warning. It was the `app/etc/modules/Php4u_BlastLuceneSearchEE.xml` including a dependency for `Enterprise_Search`, which doesn't exist in CE. Turns out M1's Config model processes module dependencies even if the module is not active.

Comment: Good to know! I assume then they will make a fix with next patch.

Comment: Also, have you noticed 404 errors when accessing problematic extension from the admin panel ? or 404 errors only show up on front-end?

Comment: @Icon We saw errors in admin as well as frontend, because the problem was happening during Magento's configuration initialization.

Comment: Catching the exception and setting `$file = 'system.log'` in the catch block worked for me.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler - Can you give a little more detail on how/where you made these changes? Thanks

Comment: @FabianSchmengler - Change in app/Mage.php - This works but only temporarily. Each new page visited gets 404. Until cache is cleared.

Comment: @sulman yes, in Mage.php and yes, you need to clear the cache

Answer (score 8):

### **1.Resolved:Invalid Secret Key issue when when a user loads the Admin**

In this patches , Magento no longer displays the `“Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.” message when a user loads the Admin`.

By changing code at

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php`

### strict all customer password to length  MAX 256:

We already know that **magento 1.x** password  minimum ***length is 6*** .

but in **this patch magento is limit max length to 256.**

This case,magento has done **changes** at function of `validate()`  of **Customer model class** .So,if anyone has *override the class and also override then they should add  below code on `that override  class`*

```
if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array('max' => self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
   $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
       ->__('Please enter a password with at most %s characters.', self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
}
```

### Add `$this->escapeHtml()` and Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape() for some files where XSS attack possible

***If anyone override these files then you should add below code to repeciev overrider class***
  1.app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Review/Detail.php

**replace**

> $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('reports')->__('Reviews for %s',
>   $product->getName());

**with**

> $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('reports')->__('Reviews for %s',
>   $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()));

2.app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Tag/Product/Detail.php

**replace**

> $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('reports')->__('Tags submitted to %s', $product->getName());

**with**

> `$this->_headerText = Mage::helper('reports')->__('Tags submitted to %s', $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()));`

3.app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php

**replace**

> `'text'      => '<a href="' . $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $product->getId())) . '" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">' . $product->getName() . '</a>'`

**with**

> `'text'      => '<a href="' . $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $product->getId())) . '" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">' . $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) . '</a>'`

4. Sales order view   billing agree : app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/billing/agreement/view/tab/info.phtml

**replace**

> `<?php echo $this->getCustomerEmail() ?>`

**with**

> `<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomerEmail()) ?>`

5. app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/content.phtml by Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape

**replace**

> `this.pageOptions += '<option value="<?php echo $helper->jsQuoteEscape($page['value']) ?>"><?php echo $helper->jsQuoteEscape($page['label']) ?></option>';`

**with**

> `$this.pageOptions += '<option value="<?php echo $helper->jsQuoteEscape($page['value']) ?>"><?php echo $helper->quoteEscape($page['label']) ?></option>';`

6. app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/image_edit.phtml by Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape

**replace**

> `<option value="<?php echo $page['value']; ?>"><?php echo $page['label']; ?></option>`

**with**

> `<option value="<?php echo $page['value']; ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($page['label']); ?></option>`

Comment: Thanks  @Amit i missed "Resolved:Invalid Secret Key issue" in my ans :). +1

Comment: you welcome :)... you have done good job on this question

Answer (score 7):

If you've already applied SUPEE-10358^, or manually patched `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php` for the "**Invalid Secret Key**" issue, then you will need to manually delete that section from the patch file:

```
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
index 2a8e63f..f2ee208 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
@@ -186,7 +186,7 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Actio
                 'message' => $_keyErrorMsg
             )));
         } else {
-                if ($_keyErrorMsg != ''){
+                if (!$_isValidFormKey){
                 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($_keyErrorMsg);
             }
             $this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
```

Additionally, if you have already fixed the "**new-pawwsord**" typo (introduced in SUPEE-10266) in  `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml` then delete that section from the patch too:

```
diff --git app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
index c5a3f82..2ff57cc 100644
--- app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
+++ app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
@@ -158,7 +158,7 @@
                             <td class="value">
                                 <!-- This is a dummy hidden field to trick firefox from auto filling the password -->
                                 <input type="password" class="input-text no-display" name="dummy" id="dummy" />

-                                    <input type="password" name="ftp_pass" id="ftp_pass" autocomplete="new-pawwsord">
+                                    <input type="password" name="ftp_pass" id="ftp_pass" autocomplete="new-password">
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
```

*^MageSupport provided SUPEE-10358 in response to an EE support ticket regarding the InvalidSecretKey issue*

Answer (score 5):

### Issue: patch does not work on vanilla 1.9.1.1

Edit 1: fix added below.

Edit 2: my fix is no longer needed, Magento provided [SUPEE-10497](https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Action-required-SUPEE-10497-available-for-users-of-Magento-Open/td-p/81942) which fixes this problem.

### Problem:

```
# file: PATCH_SUPEE-10415_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2017-11-27-05-47-08.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Review/Detail.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Tag/Product/Detail.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Add.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Filename.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 90.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 651 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 661 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Serialized.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Form/Decorator/Form.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/billing/agreement/view/tab/info.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/content.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/image_edit.phtml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/backup.js
checking file lib/Varien/Filter/FormElementName.php
```

The vanilla Magento 1.9.1.1 was downloaded from https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/archive/1.9.1.1.tar.gz

Previously applied patches on this Magento 1.9.1.1:

```
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-6237 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1 | 8b216c42e2e5d2cb5d8e500fcb6690abede9df52 | Fri Jun 12 13:39:59 2015 +0300 | v1.14.2.0..HEAD
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v2 | 7226d88b1eeb07a5fbc4e62be189a5219457cc14 | Mon Jun 22 16:32:26 2015 +0300 | 202596e441..7226d88b1e
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 | 2349a68440e870cd68dfa81fb982f3b7a42cd099 | Fri Oct 23 14:49:16 2015 +0300 | b240663
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-7405-CE-1-9-1-1 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 | f1c57f70de3fc2bea64bbe3ddf3bdf076b750f8e | Tue Jan 19 15:29:35 2016 +0200 | 2349a68440..f1c57f70de
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-7405 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1.1 | 38d673b4d2b132c6df53becc9d92346aa5d9627e | Fri Feb 5 13:28:39 2016 +0200 | f1c57f70de3fc2bea64bbe3ddf3bdf076b750f8e..38d673b4d2b132c6df53becc9d92346aa5d9627e
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0 | v1 | 1609c0d0be86473d357346fa51f93c12b365d7a1 | Tue Dec 8 12:53:31 2015 +0200 | e1fc3c59c9587427b8a9c88655715f27afbfe970..1609c0d0be86473d357346fa51f93c12b365d7a1
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-8167 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1 | 87bb97f9b0b2871f842b7faabf667a81806f937e | Thu Apr 27 13:31:21 2017 +0300 | 6010eb82..87bb97f9b
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-8788 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v2 | 8d9fad1daf5131de3430ef09b0816d3d133c8412 | Mon Sep 26 14:06:18 2016 +0300 | 38d673b4d2..8d9fad1daf
2017-11-29 07:37:12 UTC | SUPEE-8967 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1 | 1fa53e9533f6f3a16f24d9b64dabef0ab7f965d7 | Thu Aug 18 16:32:48 2016 +0300 | 97d160644..1fa53e9533
2017-11-29 07:37:13 UTC | SUPEE-9652 | EE_1.14.3.1 | v1 | 4038f0785d828794083f53f10c01aaa6af403523 | Tue Jan 24 15:03:12 2017 +0200 | 9586981e6ca8b255014b242d50b68b88525b0754..4038f0785d828794083f53f10c01aaa6af403523
2017-11-29 07:37:13 UTC | PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v2 | CE_1.9.3.0 | v2 | 6566db274beaeb9bcdb56a62e02cc2da532e618c | Thu Jun 22 04:30:03 2017 +0300 | v1.14.3.3..HEAD
2017-11-29 07:37:13 UTC | SUPEE-10336_v1.14.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1 | 721708ecf41f0ee745b8f441a4bfe56471b493a7 | Fri Sep 8 17:55:44 2017 +0300 | cc0d87..721708e
2017-11-29 07:37:13 UTC | SUPEE-10266-CE-1.9.1.1 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 | f66c6bcd3c16c5ca934823e6a91b5696698e497c | Fri Sep 1 12:15:53 2017 +0300 | 8d9fad1daf5131de3430ef09b0816d3d133c8412..HEAD
```

### Official fix for SUPEE-10415 patch for 1.9.1.1:

- If you installed `SUPEE-10266`:
  Revert it using:
  `./PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2017-09-15-04-59-56.sh --revert`
- If you installed `SUPEE-10415`:
  Revert it using
  `./PATCH_SUPEE-10415_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2017-11-27-05-47-08.sh --revert`
- Now apply [SUPEE-10497](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2138)

### Manual fix for SUPEE-10415 patch for 1.9.1.1 [deprecated]:

Edit the file `PATCH_SUPEE-10415_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2017-11-27-05-47-08.sh`, replace lines `445`-`447`.

Old:

```
         $fileInfo = getimagesize($filePath);
         if (is_array($fileInfo) and isset($fileInfo[2])) {
             if ($this->isImageType($fileInfo[2])) {
```

New:

```
         list($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $fileType) = getimagesize($filePath);
         if ($fileType) {
             if ($this->isImageType($fileType)) {
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. Seems to be an issue with `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php`. Patch SUPEE-10415 doesn't appear to take into consideration the modification made by Patch SUPEE-9767 (v1 or v2)

Comment: Fix added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Patch cannot be applied to vanilla 1.9.2.2 as well, the earliest break occurs in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php`.

Comment: I don't agree. We took a vanilla install from https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/archive/1.9.2.2.tar.gz and were able to apply patches in this order:

SUPEE-7405-CE-1-9-2-2 | CE_1.9.2.2 | v1, 
SUPEE-7405 | CE_1.9.2.2 | v1.1, 
SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0 | v1,
SUPEE-8167 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1, 
SUPEE-8788 | CE_1.9.2.2 | v2,
SUPEE-8967 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1,
SUPEE-9652 | EE_1.14.3.1 | v1,
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v2 | CE_1.9.3.0 | v2,
SUPEE-10336_v1.14.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1,
SUPEE-10266-CE-1.9.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1,
SUPEE-10415-ce-1.9.2.2 | CE_1.9.2.2 | v1

Comment: I am using magento-1.9.2.2-2015-10-27-03-14-30.zip from the official site. Uploaded and extracted to a linux box, coped the patch file for 1.9.2.2 over. Result: https://pastebin.com/BCvsKaBW

Comment: You need to apply all previous patches, see my previous comment.
I tested it.

Comment: @JeroenVermeulen-MageHost You should run the other patches rather then running that manual fix that particular fix is handled within Patch 9767 you should apply that instead because there are other vulnerabilities that get fixed in that patch. That patch has two versions if you installed the first version previously make sure you uninstall it and install the v2.

Comment: @danmentzer Did you test it? In my description of the problem is a full list of the patches I installed on 1.9.1.1, which includes 9767 v2.

Comment: Please use SUPEE-10497 instead, it was just recently released to address this problem on 1.9.1.1. Please read the release notes as this patch requires removing SUPEE-10266 prior to installation.

Comment: @PiotrKaminski do you have a link to the release notes? I can only find reference to this in the release archive, and there it currently states it combines SUPEE-10266 and SUPEE-10497 (probably a typo) [link](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?_ga=2.174273764.779305289.1512991829-1190708971.1505741373#download2138)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete change log and what I understand with this changelog

And which files were affected by what cause is listed below

**Escape Html change**

file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Review/Detail.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Tag/Product/Detail.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Add.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/billing/agreement/view/tab/info.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/content.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/image_edit.phtml
js/mage/adminhtml/backup.js
```

**Add DS instead '/'**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
```

**new file added**

```
app/code/core/Zend/Form/Decorator/Form.php
lib/Varien/Filter/FormElementName.php
```

**Complete change file**

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Filename.php

```
 class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Filename extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
 {
+
+ /**
+ * Config path for system log file.
+ */
+ const DEV_LOG_FILE_PATH = 'dev/log/file';
+
+ /**
+ * Config path for exception log file.
+ */
+ const DEV_LOG_EXCEPTION_FILE_PATH = 'dev/log/exception_file';
+
+ /**
+ * Processing object before save data
+ *
+ * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Filename
+ * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
+ */
 protected function _beforeSave()
 {
- $value = $this->getValue();
- $value = basename($value);
+ $value = $this->getValue();
+ $configPath = $this->getPath();
+ $value = basename($value);
+
+ // if dev/log setting, validate log file extension.
+ if ($configPath == self::DEV_LOG_FILE_PATH || $configPath == self::DEV_LOG_EXCEPTION_FILE_PATH) {
+ if (!Mage::helper('log')->isLogFileExtensionValid($value)) {
+ throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__
+ ('Invalid file extension used for log file. Allowed file extensions: log, txt, html, csv'));
+ }
+ }
+
     $this->setValue($value);
     return $this;
 }
```

**Added method getCacheId() and getServiceUrl()**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Helper/Data.php
```

**Added method unserialize()**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php
```

**Use getServiceUrl() method created in app/code/core/Mage/Api/Helper/Data.php**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php
```

**Use getCacheId() method created in app/code/core/Mage/Api/Helper/Data.php**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config.php
```

**Used above `unserialize()` method created in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Serialized.php
app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

**Comment change**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
```

**Comment added**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
```

**Added Maximum password length**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
```

**Added allow file extension** //$_allowedFileExtensions = array('log', 'txt', 'html', 'csv');

```
app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php
```

**Don't know what change**

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
```

**Issue List**

[SUPEE-10415 prevents basket control](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203763/supee-10415-prevents-basket-control)

[get error code of #10415 in paypal in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160804/get-error-code-of-10415-in-paypal-in-magento)

Answer (score 1):

Attempting this on Magento EE 1.13.0.2 and it seems this patch doesn't play nice if SUPEE-6482 is installed.

```
Checking patch app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php...
error: while searching for:
            ->setUseSession(false);

        $wsdlUrl = $params !== null
            ? $urlModel->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true, '_query' => $params))
            : $urlModel->getUrl('*/*/*');

        if( $withAuth ) {
            $phpAuthUser = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_USER', false);

error: patch failed: app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php:205
```

SUPEE-6482 changed the line with `$phpAuthUser` to

```
$phpAuthUser = rawurlencode($this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_USER', false));
```

Comment: Not only was the `$phpAuthUser` line different the spacing before `->setUseSession(false);` was also incorrect