# 'Unsupported data type N' after patching SUPEE-10415

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10415

after patching SUPEE-10415, 
saving products in backend causes an error,

Unsupported data type N

does it have to do something with the database?
maybe some settings there?

any advice would be really helpfull

Answer (score 9):

See:
[Security Patch SUPEE-10415 - Possible Issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues/203795#203795)

You basically need to have `SUPEE-8788 V2` installed.

Failing that download Magento 1.9.3.7 and copy

- `lib/Unserialize/Parser.php`
- `lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php`
- `lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php`
- `lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php`

files from that installation to your site and see if there are any changes between the files and overwrite them if there are.

Comment: 8788 v2 was installed allready but i installed it again but it doesn´t make a difference

Comment: yes, they are differnet, should i update this files then?

Comment: this solved the situation, many thanks for your help Matt!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Magento 1.9.2.4.
Rolled back all SUPEE patches until the version SUPEE 8787 V1 (including this one) according to the

```
app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

and installed SUPEE-8788 V2 instead. Then installed all the patches again and the exception was gone.

Compared the files

- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
- lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
- lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
- lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php

with the files from the version 1.9.3.7 and the content was the same, except comments in the file headers

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered similar problem (Unsupported data type N) on CE 1.9.2.4 after applying 10415 - this was on saving shopping cart rules in admin & on the front end the user was presented w/ rule couldn't be applied.

I overwrote the lib/Unserialize/ files from 1.9.3.7 & now all is good - shopping cart rules can be saved & applied as expected.

Thanks Matt Antley

PS - if you just apply the lib/Unserialize/ files from SUPEE-8788 V2 you'll get a class not found error

Answer (score 0):

My solution for magento 1.9.1.0

- Download Magento ver 1.9.3.1
- Copy folder lib/Unserialize from ver 1.9.3.1 to 1.9.1.0

and works :)

an some cases you can not revert patches.
Just fix bug.