# Security Patch SUPEE 10415

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10415

After I implemented the patch SUPEE 10415, checkout cart url /checkout/cart/ got an error, and when I reverted the Patch it now works as expected but I need to implement the patch asap.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi
Please share the error you are facing.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the error in checkout/cart url http://prntscr.com/hirbry

Comment: Here is the exact error.                               
lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php(102): Unserialize_Reader_ArrValue->read('N', ';')

Comment: @JmCabugnason Did you apply the 10415 patch?

Answer (score 1):

After patching SUPEE-10415, causes an error “Unsupported data type N”
Solution:
The cause of this issue is not having SUPEE-8788 V2 installed.
To fix this, download Magento 1.9.3.7 and copy

```
lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
```

files to your website. check if any changes between files.

Please take [Security Patch SUPEE-10415 - Possible Issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues) as reference.

Comment: You are Most welcome @JmCabugnason

Comment: If you copy another answer please state your source. This is a copy of https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203970/146

Comment: @Meetanshi After install SUPEE 10415 both front-end and back-end getting 404 error, how can i solve this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215620/57334

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

(1) First revert the patch if applied.

(2) Check your current magento version and download same fresh version.

(3) Just put `lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php` file from downloded version

(4) Now apply patch again .

Error will be resolved.
Dont forget to clear cache.