# Error "Cannot add the item to shopping cart" after upgrade magento 1.9.1.1 to 1.9.3.7

Tags: cart, magento1.9.3.7

Getting error on all add to cart links on product listing page.

=> Please assist me. Thanks!

Comment: No. i have just download magento new version and replace all file on root folder with new version.

Comment: Than try to check error log. What is it saying ?

Comment: Try enabling errors logs, and check what errors come

Comment: Exception message: Unsupported data type N

 httpdocs/lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php(102): Unserialize_Reader_ArrValue->read('N', ';')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be because of form key. You need to add following line to add form key just after form tag in give file list

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

> 1) For Add to cart in product view
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
>
> 2) For login & customer registration
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/persistent/customer/form/registration.phtml
>
> 3) Update cart
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/checkout/cart.phtml

If this is fine then also possible because of new patches. Please
Check:
[Security Patch SUPEE-10415 - Possible Issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues)

https://gist.github.com/balloz/ceaf5feb5ac66caaa82342441d32aa88

Comment: i am getting this error on product listing page. on button.

Comment: http://www.enhgo.com/code/fix-for-broken-dentures/
May be this can help you

Comment: Getting same this error :
https://www.queryxchange.com/q/10_208946/cannot-add-items-to-cart-view-cart-after-upgrade-to-ce-1-9-3-7/

Comment: yes supee 10415 creates conflict sometime
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203968/unsupported-data-type-n-after-patching-supee-10415

Comment: Thanks @Sameer Bhayani , I have resolved this error from your below link.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues