# How to solve Security patch 10415 Error?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, supee-10415

After installing Security patch 10415, both frontend and backend return 404 error. How can I solve this error?

Note: No log error found.

Comment: please don't change the question completely. If you have a different question ask a different one. Don't destroy content

Comment: @Marius Okay. again I won't.

Comment: @Marius After applied PATCH_SUPEE-10415 website getting 404 error both frontend and backend

Comment: @Marius : I just want an answer to my post, that's why I am slightly modified.

Comment: try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204020/after-applying-supee-10415-magento-1-9-3-3-404s-but-works-fine-if-redis-is-remov

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have all previous security patches applied or there will be conflicts like the ones listed above.

A `hunk FAILED` error is when the content within the file being patched doesn't match up with what the patch is trying to replace.

I would test your site on http://magereport.com/ and see which patches it flags up and then install them.

Comment: I need to install patch 9767 v2 before that need to revert patch 9767 v1,  i try that getting too many error, could you pls hekp me get out this issue, mt error https://justpaste.it/1e9pn how can i remove that.    :::: What is Unreversed patch detected! Ignore -R? [n] how can i deal with saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Admin

Comment: I would checkout your app/etc/applied.patches.list and search for app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv and it will say which patches have modified this file. For instance, SUPEE-10266 modifies this file, so if you're trying to revert 9767 v1 (To apply v2) then you will need to revert 10266 first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about installing all the previous patches of this patch(PATCH_SUPEE-10415_CE_1.9.2.3_v1-2017-11-27-06-50-52.sh) try to compare the code diff in the patch file to that of the file where the hunk is failing.

In your case it is failing at app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php. Open that file and compare changes with the patch file, apply it manually and remove that diff from the patch file and again run the patch. Repeat it till the fails are zero. It will help sometimes.

Comment: after solved errors, if i applied 10415 patch, website not working, return 404 error. How can i solve this error?