# Patch Installation - Security Patch SUPEE-10415 return 404 error Both Front-End & Back-End

Tags: magento-1.9, php, supee-10415

I try to install `Security Patch SUPEE-10415`, after successfully installed my front-end and back-end getting `404 error`.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues

Comment: Thanks, can you be added error log and .htacess file. i will check