# Is security patch SUPEE-10570 compatible for Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.1?

Tags: magento-enterprise, patches, supee-10570

I have Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.1 installed. So do i need to apply security patch SUPEE-10570? Is it compatible with Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

According to their security patch notes [here](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10570) you need to apply that patch. I'll just rewrite only the important parts:

> Patches and upgrades are available for the following Magento versions:
>
> **Magento Commerce 1.9.0.0-1.14.3.7**: SUPEE-10570 or upgrade to Magento
>   Commerce 1.14.3.8
>
> **Magento Open Source 1.5.0.0-1.9.3.7**: SUPEE-10570 or upgrade to Magento Open Source 1.9.3.8

It also says that the security flaw affects `Magento Commerce prior to 1.14.3.8` which means it affects version **`1.14.2.1`**.

**Magento Commerce** is `Magento Enterprise`.
**Magento Open Source** is `Magento Community Edition`.

Comment: After successfully applied patch-10570, front and backend not working. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Post another question on the website with as much details you can give( errors messages, screenshots etc.)

Comment: Already someone post, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215620/57334

Comment: That question is for patch 10415, you need help for 10570.

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: @AdrianZ. Thanks for your answer, Helpful.