# password doesn´t match after patch SUPEE 10415

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, patches, supee-10415

I get an error message after applied the patch SUPEE-10415

At checkout as guest, trying to create a new customer account doesn't work.

Using a custom theme from template monster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-10415 - Possible Issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues)

Answer (score 0):

`SUPEE 10415` - added Maximum password length set is 256 character and validation check in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`.

can you please check you override this method.

Hope it will helpful for you

Comment: do i need to change something in this file, or in my theme? thanks for your advice

Comment: do not change file. just check this file is override or not?

Comment: yes it has been overwritten yesterday when patch applied

Comment: https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blame/master/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php#L884

check your code 884 the code is added  in your customer.php file