# New SUPEE-10497 Patch for 1.9.1.1 version possible issue?

Tags: patches, security, magento-1.9.1.1

> A new patch (SUPEE-10497) is available for merchants using Magento Open Source 1.9.1.1. This patch replaces SUPEE-10266 (released September 14, 2017) and SUPEE-10415 (released November 28, 2017).

**Do I need to patch?**

> **This issue affects users of Magento Open Source 1.9.1.1 only**. Users of Magento Commerce, or any other version of Magento Open Source, are not affected.
>
> This patch combines SUPEE-10415 and SUPEE-10266 for Magento Open Source 1.9.1.1. To install, remove both patches first then install SUPEE-10497.

Comment: Great, would be interesting to know what the issue is that this specific patch solves with regard to 1.9.1.1. Can't find anything on this so far...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues?answertab=active#tab-top . provide clear ans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most recent patch installed  follow some Action required. It is only for **Magento version 1.9.1.1**.

> SUPEE-10266 - Remove this patch, and install SUPEE-10497.
>
> SUPEE-10415 - Remove this patch and SUPEE-10266, and install SUPEE-10497.
>
> SUPEE-9767    - No need to remove this patch. Just install patch bundle SUPEE-10497

---

**How to apply and revert patch?**

Please follow the Magento document

http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf

---

**For more reference :**

[Security Patch SUPEE-10415 - Possible Issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues?answertab=active#tab-top)