# After Update to Magento 1.9.2.4 and SUPEE-10415 no card items

Tags: magento1.9.2.4, supee-10415

After Update to Magento 1.9.2.4 and SUPEE-10415 we have no card items, after adding products to the basket.

Is there any know issue ( f.e. Form-Key ) which we can check?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check this topic: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues

Comment: can you provide some screen shot it will help me to understand

Comment: Hi, sv3n i check this out, but can not find a solution. Problem is, if i click on add to basket and proceed to card page the card is empty. The url looks like this (Request): https://THESHOP_URL.COM/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdGFnZS13d3cucmVpbWt1bHR1ci1zaG9wLmRlLw,,/product/1837/form_key/TVgWS7ZkmS4TkN2K/