# Why are there SUPEE patches for different 1.9.3.x version when the only difference is the "index" line?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I was wondering why are there different **files/patches** for different versions of **Magento 1.9.3.x?**

I have compared the patches for SUPEE-10415 **1.9.3.1** vs **1.9.3.3** vs **1.9.3.6.** The only line that is different is the **"index"** line which doesn't essentially make a difference when patching, at least I haven't noticed a difference.

Similar for **SUPEE-10570**, v2, patches **1.9.3.0-1.9.3.1** vs **1.9.3.2-1.9.3.7** seem identical except for the **"index"** lines.

As explained above my concerns are for patches of 1.9.3.x versions, not diff between 1.9.2.x vs 1.9.3.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-10415 - Possible Issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203567/security-patch-supee-10415-possible-issues)

Comment: different patch versions for code difference in every magento versions

Comment: @magenx the issue is that there doesn't seem to be a code diff for 1.9.3.x patches. It is confusing to have a huge list of same patches whose only diff is the index line. At least from my point of view

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a diff on `PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.2.4_v2.sh` and `PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.3.7_v2.sh`, there's definitely more different than just the `index` lines.

See here:

```
$ diff PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.2.4_v2.sh PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.3.7_v2.sh                                                                      
160c160
< SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1 | fc43e39da184f3f6053fab31d30d620aedc542b9 | Fri Mar 16 13:14:14 2018 +0200 | ce-1.9.2.4-dev
---
> SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.3.7 | CE_1.9.3.7 | v1 | 418f82905c75afc286ae12fd70869429cf16aa37 | Fri Mar 16 13:12:38 2018 +0200 | ce-1.9.3.7-dev
164c164
< index 4c0947b..a83ed29 100644
---
> index d66756b..949f47d 100644
176c176
< index f70a192..144bbba 100644
---
> index 4e09ab3..d0ee857 100644
195c195
< index 94a2ff2..44c58e1 100644
---
> index d6768b8..f5c5d28 100644
210c210
< index 4a109af..4c644f1 100644
---
> index dccc979..084a820 100644
254c254
< index 439085e..bbe2b82 100644
---
> index 0da4d48..57d04de 100644
275c275
< index 71f03fe..b05550b 100644
---
> index 3b065c6..7cbbd50 100644
288c288
< index 8ce94a1..33b8f8a 100644
---
> index f64c063..4116c2a 100644
305c305
< index 404530e..8ff69ee 100644
---
> index 5a12b55..1d6d4d6 100644
317c317
< index 529251f..2fd8ef9 100644
---
> index ba1ccf9..60131bf 100644
330c330
< index bad853e..2dc0747 100644
---
> index 64bff6b..aad8429 100644
343c343
< index 1d03f2f..918b26b 100644
---
> index c6854dc..8abecc1 100644
356c356
< index b89cc79..fd7f4cf 100644
---
> index 9806072..e5ac4a0 100644
375c375
< index 28b5174..55276eb 100644
---
> index 0bd366b..8471f0a 100644
391c391
< index 1ca6a8b..adf76e2 100644
---
> index 0f35790..dbbe27a 100644
403c403
< index 385290e..90489e3 100644
---
> index afad880..32caa42 100644
434c434
< index 83ae14c..7f4fb1e 100644
---
> index 351e6be..41b5255 100644
455c455
< index 2fac289..07fe9a1 100644
---
> index 1b7916b..dd90f7e 100644
476,529d475
< diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
< index fcc0a807..3a18cd0 100644
< --- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
< +++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
< @@ -32,6 +32,7 @@ class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien extends Varien_Object
<      const VALIDATOR_HTTP_X_FORVARDED_FOR_KEY    = 'http_x_forwarded_for';
<      const VALIDATOR_HTTP_VIA_KEY                = 'http_via';
<      const VALIDATOR_REMOTE_ADDR_KEY             = 'remote_addr';
< +    const VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP    = 'session_expire_timestamp';
<      const SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY               = '_secure_cookie_check';
<  
<      /**
< @@ -383,6 +384,16 @@ class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien extends Varien_Object
<      }
<  
<      /**
< +     * Use session expire timestamp in validator key
< +     *
< +     * @return bool
< +     */
< +    public function useValidateSessionExpire()
< +    {
< +        return $this->getCookie()->getLifetime() > 0;
< +    }
< +
< +    /**
<       * Retrieve skip User Agent validation strings (Flash etc)
<       *
<       * @return array
< @@ -451,6 +462,15 @@ class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien extends Varien_Object
<              return false;
<          }
<  
< +        if ($this->useValidateSessionExpire()
< +            && isset($sessionData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP])
< +            && $sessionData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP] < time() ) {
< +            return false;
< +        } else {
< +            $this->_data[self::VALIDATOR_KEY][self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP]
< +                = $validatorData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP];
< +        }
< +
<          return true;
<      }
<  
< @@ -484,6 +504,8 @@ class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien extends Varien_Object
<              $parts[self::VALIDATOR_HTTP_USER_AGENT_KEY] = (string)$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
<          }
<  
< +        $parts[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP] = time() + $this->getCookie()->getLifetime();
< +
<          return $parts;
<      }
<  
531c477
< index 913347d..2f0a27d 100644
---
> index 8f4baf8..87e1dac 100644
547c493
< index d2ea8d9..d3d6333 100644
---
> index b87cf72..54aaba1 100644
554,555c500,501
< -            <version>1.6.2.0.4</version>
< +            <version>1.6.2.0.4.1.2</version>
---
> -            <version>1.6.2.0.5</version>
> +            <version>1.6.2.0.5.1.2</version>
559c505
< diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.4.1.1-1.6.2.0.4.1.2.php app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.4.1.1-1.6.2.0.4.1.2.php
---
> diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.5.1.1-1.6.2.0.5.1.2.php app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.5.1.1-1.6.2.0.5.1.2.php
563c509
< +++ app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.4.1.1-1.6.2.0.4.1.2.php
---
> +++ app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.5.1.1-1.6.2.0.5.1.2.php
604c550
< index af06fc6..105ea1b 100644
---
> index f61934c..b509365 100644
626c572
< index 8cf83db..8766781 100644
---
> index c929d9c..e67eae8 100644
681c627
< index 9eba8ab..ca3537e 100644
---
> index 534d407..b1448b0 100644
696c642
< index 6b3589d..78b5e26 100644
---
> index b3d8a92..0dfb3a6 100644
721c667
< @@ -790,6 +796,22 @@ class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product extends Mage_ImportExport_Mo
---
> @@ -797,6 +803,22 @@ class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product extends Mage_ImportExport_Mo
744c690
< @@ -2113,6 +2135,7 @@ class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product extends Mage_ImportExport_Mo
---
> @@ -2160,6 +2182,7 @@ class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product extends Mage_ImportExport_Mo
753c699
< index c441fc5..ddac1ac 100644
---
> index f6b425a..5373555 100644
784c730
< index e429656..d8097e0 100644
---
> index b10376e..f7e8004 100644
818c764
< index 6125c52..bb453d3 100644
---
> index aae3bea..a2f6f5a 100644
857c803
< index 55d66d6..a39641e 100644
---
> index cf15b8e..8a3b176 100644
879c825
< index 77975c8..aadbc0f 100644
---
> index d731dad..401fa70 100644
933c879
< index ee10e7e..09c5882 100644
---
> index 0ae9060..274e304 100644
946c892
< index 70878d1..92d295c 100644
---
> index e2f460d..7ce5129 100644
973c919
< index 435b4ed..6823f11 100644
---
> index 51aa26f..031e0fc 100644
996c942
< index 975f26f..31cff23 100644
---
> index e6331bb..4505171 100644
1009c955
< index 66903dd..0d8eb50 100644
---
> index 3647163..5d2db87 100644
1022c968
< index 05c8bfb..82b9a4a 100644
---
> index cc50e4a..edfaadc 100644
1035c981
< index f6e9084..8ba1a56 100644
---
> index ce3053c..6dfe1af 100644
1048c994
< index d4dcf6d..d4ab938 100644
---
> index 90ccbca..03e117f 100644
1061c1007
< index bf08930..392d675 100644
---
> index 30aa8c1..608aa4f 100644
1091c1037
< index 2c2e0bc..aa7adff 100644
---
> index 53a2700..a665d18 100644
1112c1058
< index 4d06686..4663c91 100644
---
> index b561f2f..2119819 100644
1135c1081
< index 900fd44..4dd7ed6 100644
---
> index 07e4403..7511468 100644
1148c1094
< index d806652..7782a0b 100644
---
> index f559794..3a1521a 100644
1161c1107
< index 74d7620..631067e 100644
---
> index 4edd458..67b3994 100644
1191c1137
< index acbe497..34fd78b 100644
---
> index bd431ec..a8beaa8 100644
1207c1153
< index c26f043..6cb99fe 100644
---
> index 1a09fc4..9ce2207 100644
1220c1166
< index 5b6df2f..6b06b16 100644
---
> index 9333906..c2931cc 100644
1233c1179
< index bbdc417..fa5167a 100644
---
> index 3ae7af5..6521473 100644
1236c1182
< @@ -713,6 +713,7 @@
---
> @@ -717,6 +717,7 @@
1245c1191
< index cb39a90..439cc44 100644
---
> index 52529cd..cc1470c 100644
1256c1202
< @@ -89,6 +90,7 @@
---
> @@ -90,6 +91,7 @@
```

Comment: I stated 1.9.3.x, there is no evident code difference for the patches mentioned in the question. :/